# How to reset variables in a sequence recognition automaton in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm a beginner with vhdl. I created a recognizer automata (Moore) of the 000010  sequence  to access an elevator. After recognizing the whole sequence, in the X1 state the elevator doors open and two LEDs light up, the doors close after 5 seconds in X2 and in X3, after 10 seconds, the elevator reaches the desired floor.
Simulating everything with Modelsim, there are no mistakes.

My problem is in wanting to reset all the variables (and then return to the initial state X0) in case, for example, you are in any state. In X1, for example, the variables "esito", led1 and led2 should return to 0.

Since it is not possible to reset these variables in the first process (where there is a reset condition = 1) because I would have the error "Can not resolve multiple constant drivers for net" (the same variables are used in both processes),  I wanted to ask you if the solution I have adopted in the following code was correct (reset the variables in X0 before the control is performed on the inserted sequence).

I hope I have been clear and you can help me.

This is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity riconoscitore is
port(   
    simbolo:inout  std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    clock,esito,reset:inout std_logic;
    led1,led2:out std_logic
    );
end riconoscitore;

architecture myriconosc of riconoscitore is
type state_values is 
(X0,X1,X2,X3);
signal current_st,next_st:state_values;
signal timer:std_logic;
begin

process(clock,reset) 
begin
if(reset='1') then
  current_st<=X0;
elsif(rising_edge(clock))then
current_st<=next_st;
end if;
end process;

process(current_st,simbolo,timer,reset)
begin
next_st<=X0;

case current_st is

when X0 =>
esito<='0';
led1<='0';
led2<='0';
reset<='0';
timer<='0';
simbolo<=('U','U','U','U','U','U');
if(simbolo="000010")then
  next_st<=X1; 
else
  next_st<=X0;
end if;

when X1 =>
esito<='1';
led1<='1';
led2<='1';
timer<= transport '1' after 5 sec;
next_st<=X2;

when X2=>
led1<='0';
if(timer='1') then
  next_st<=X3;
  reset<= transport '1' after 10 sec;
else next_st<=X2;
end if;

when X3=>
if (reset='1') then
  next_st<=X0;
  esito<='U';
  reset<='U';
  timer<='U';
  simbolo<=('U','U','U','U','U','U');
  led2<='0';
else 
  next_st<=X3;
end if;

end case;
end process;

end myriconosc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reset in your sequential process is *asynchronous*:

```
process(clock,reset) 
begin
if(reset='1') then
  current_st<=X0;
elsif(rising_edge(clock))then
current_st<=next_st;
end if;
end process;
```

Only use an asynchronous reset to put flip-flops into a known state when some exception occurs, the most common by far being power-up. Never ever use an asynchronous reset for any other purpose. Never ever us an asynchronous reset as part of the normal operation of your circuit.

So, for example, suppose you had a stop watch with two buttons: *START/STOP* and *RESET*. So, at the start of the race, the timekeeper would press *START/STOP* to start the watch counting and at the end of the race the timekeeper would press *START/STOP* again to stop the watch counting. Once the time has been recorded, the timekeeper would then press *RESET* to set the watch to zero ready for the next race. Suppose after a while, the battery runs out. The timekeeper would put new batteries in and would find the the stop watch is already reset ready for the next race. You could use an asynchronous reset to reset the watch in the second (new batteries) case; you should never ever use one in the first case, because that is not an exception - resetting to zero ready for the next race is what stop watches do as part of their normal operation.

So, an asynchronous reset should only each be connected to sequential processes (like the one above) and should be used to put the flip-flops *unconditionally* into a known state (ie the state on reset should not depend on any other signal). If you do not follow these rules you will not have a *synchronous design* and will cause yourself problems.

So, in your design, you should use the asynchronous reset to put your flip-flops in a known state - `X0` (as you have done) - and the state outputs of the FSM when in that state is the state they have at reset. That's it. If you don't like the state of the outputs in the `X0` state, then you need to change that or you need to reset the flip-flops to a different state.

Answer (score 0):

**One**
The reason you have problems is that you have not followed the coding rules for HDL.

You have two section: a registers/clocked section and a combinatorial section.

In the combinatorial section you **must** give a value to each signal & variable in each state. If you forget that you create latches. Latches should be avoided, certainly if you only start programming.
These latches keep their value and that is what is causing your problems.

There are two solutions:

1. Assign a value to each signal & variable in each state.
2. Use a default

**Two**
There is a second error which I have not seen before:
Your `process(clock,reset)` depends on the reset. In that process you set the state.

Then in the next process you use the state to set the reset. You have just created a most nasty circular state machine!
Remove ALL usage of reset from the second process. The reset should only control your first process!

Comment: Ah yes, I come from Verilog where we only have signals and I often refer to signals as variables. I'll update the text.